# Install pcl_ros in ros foxy

Tags: python, c++, package, ubuntu-20.04, ros2

I´ve been trying to install PCL_ROS package for ROS 2 Foxy. Whenever I try, this error appears:

```
enter code here[0.482s] WARNING:colcon.colcon_core.package_selection:Some selected packages are already built in one or more underlay workspaces:


'pcl_conversions' is in: /home/juan-orozco/ros2_ws/install/pcl_conversions, /opt/ros/foxy
If a package in a merged underlay workspace is overridden and it installs headers, then all packages in the overlay must sort their include directories by workspace order. Failure to do so may result in build failures or undefined behavior at run time.
If the overridden package is used by another package in any underlay, then the overriding package in the overlay must be API and ABI compatible or undefined behavior at run time may occur.

If you understand the risks and want to override a package anyways, add the following to the command line:
    --allow-overriding pcl_conversions

This may be promoted to an error in a future release of colcon-override-check.
Starting >>> pcl_conversions
Finished <<< pcl_conversions [19.1s]                       
Starting >>> pcl_ros
--- stderr: pcl_ros                               
/home/juan-orozco/ros2_ws/src/perception_pcl/pcl_ros/tools/pcd_to_pointcloud.cpp: In constructor ‘pcl_ros::PCDPublisher::PCDPublisher(const rclcpp::NodeOptions&)’:
/home/juan-orozco/ros2_ws/src/perception_pcl/pcl_ros/tools/pcd_to_pointcloud.cpp:88:66: error: no matching function for call to ‘pcl_ros::PCDPublisher::declare_parameter<std::string>(const char [10])’
   88 |     file_name_ = this->declare_parameter<std::string>("file_name");
      |                                                                  ^
In file included from /opt/ros/foxy/include/rclcpp/node.hpp:1224,
                 from /opt/ros/foxy/include/rclcpp/executors/single_threaded_executor.hpp:28,
                 from /opt/ros/foxy/include/rclcpp/executors.hpp:22,
                 from /opt/ros/foxy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp:146,
                 from /home/juan-orozco/ros2_ws/src/perception_pcl/pcl_ros/tools/pcd_to_pointcloud.cpp:57:
/opt/ros/foxy/include/rclcpp/node_impl.hpp:157:1: note: candidate: ‘auto rclcpp::Node::declare_parameter(const string&, const ParameterT&, const ParameterDescriptor&, bool) [with ParameterT = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; rcl_interfaces::msg::ParameterDescriptor = rcl_interfaces::msg::ParameterDescriptor_<std::allocator<void> >]’
  157 | Node::declare_parameter(
      | ^~~~
/opt/ros/foxy/include/rclcpp/node_impl.hpp:157:1: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 1 provided
/home/juan-orozco/ros2_ws/src/perception_pcl/pcl_ros/tools/pcd_to_pointcloud.cpp:99:42: error: ‘using element_type = class rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeTopicsInterface’ {aka ‘class rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeTopicsInterface’} has no member named ‘resolve_topic_name’
   99 |       this->get_node_topics_interface()->resolve_topic_name(cloud_topic_);
      |                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/pcd_to_pointcloud_lib.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/pcd_to_pointcloud_lib.dir/tools/pcd_to_pointcloud.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:109: CMakeFiles/pcd_to_pointcloud_lib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< pcl_ros [18.6s, exited with code 2]

Summary: 1 package finished [38.0s]
  1 package failed: pcl_ros
  1 package had stderr output: pcl_ros
  2 packages not processed
```

I just installed ROS2 Foxy and I really don't know what's going on

Please, help me.

Comment: are you try to build from the `foxy` branch of pcl_ros ? 
It seems that there is a mismatch between ROS version and pcl_ros version

Answer (score 0):

I advise to use Humble, the latest stable version of ROS.
And and update pcl_ros package to last version.
Can you give me more information about how you build the package and ROS2 ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).